# Does Google's "Continue As" Login Pop Up Pose a Privacy Threat?

Tags: privacy

In couple sites such as tripadvisor.com I've noticed a pop up from Google prompting me to sign in ("Continue as "). The pop up is not requested by my actions and it's embedded into the site AND it contains my email address and my real name.

Doesn't this allow websites snoop users by extracting these pieces of information from the pop up? How can I stop this from happening and why isn't anyone else talking about this?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1414410/how-to-disable-google-one-tap-sign-up-prompts